# HTML and javascript username validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

For my school project we have to make a sign up page and check if the input is valid.
This is my code so far but the validity check won't work.

I am trying to make a button that checks validity and turns another button into submit but it wont work for some reason.

```js
function CheckAll() {
  var flag = true;
  var length = document.getElementById('user').value.length;
  var value = document.getElementById('user').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!(value.charAt(i) >= '0' && value.charAt(i) <= '9') || (value.charAt(i) >= 'a' && value.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (value.charAt(i) >= 'A' && value.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) {
      alert("username must be made of characters and numbers only");
      flag = false;
    }
  }
  var lengthPass = document.getElementById('password').value.length;
  var valuePass = document.getElementById('password').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < lengthPass; i++) {
    if (!(valuePass.charAt(i) >= '0' && valuePass.charAt(i) <= '9') || (valuePass.charAt(i) >= 'a' && valuePass.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (valuePass.charAt(i) >= 'A' && valuePass.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) {
      alert("Password must be made of characters and numbers only");
      flag = false;
    }

  }
  if (!(length >= 6 || length <= 20)) {
    alert("Username Must be 6-20 Characters long");
  }
  if (!(lengthPass >= 6 || lengthPass <= 20)) {
    alert("Password must be 6-20 characters long")
    flag = true;

  }
  var valueMail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var check = false;
  var shtrudel = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < valueMail.length; i++) {
    if (value.chatAt(i) == '@') {
      shtrudel++;
      for (var j = i; j < valueMail.length; j++) {
        if (valueMail.charAt(j) == '.') {
          check = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (shtrudel > 1) {
    alert("You're only allowed to have 1 '@' sign");
  }
  if (!check) {
    alert("Your email has to include a '@' sign and a '.' sign");
  }
  var valuePhone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  var lengthPgone = document.getElementById('phone').value.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!((valuePhone.charAt(i) >= '0' || valuePhone.charAt(i) <= '9') && (valuePhone.length != 7))) {
      flag = false;


    }
  }
// ------ missing a } ----- //

function AgreeCheck() {
  var Check = document.getElementById("agree").checked;
  var Button = document.getElementById("submit");
  if (Check && (CheckAll)) {
    Button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    Button.removeAttribute("style");
  } else {
    Button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    Button.setAttribute("style", "color:grey");

  }
}
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url("Images/cup630.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150%;
}

form {
  color: red
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.cancelbtn,
.signupbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .cancelbtn,
  .signupbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="HomePage.html" id="form">
  Name+Last Name: <input type="text" name="names" />
  <br />
  <br /> Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="user" />
  <br />
  <p style="font-size:70%">must contain 6-20 character</p>
  <br /> Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
  <br />
  <p style="font-size:70%">must contain 6-20</p>
  <br /> E-mail: <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
  <br /> Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
  <br /> Enter Your Birth Date:
  <br />
  <br /> Day <input type="text" name="day" /> Month <input type="text" name="month" /> Year <input type="text" name="year" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Enter Your Favourite Esports Game:
  <select>
                <option>League Of Legends</option>
                <option>Dota</option>
                <option>StarCraft</option>
                <option>Street Fighter</option>
                <option>Smite</option>
                <option>Mortal Kombat</option>
                <option>Heroes Of The Storm</option>
                <option>Super Smash Bros</option>
                <option>Call of Duty</option>
                <option>Counter Strike: Global Offensive</option>
                <option>I Dont Watch Esports</option>
            </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" name="agree" id="agree" value="check validity" onclick="AgreeCheck()" />
  <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem, how does it not work?

Comment: As you can see had you created a snippet like I did for you, you are missing a } - look at the code and the console. I marked it `// ------ missing a } ----- //`
Also NEVER call anything is a form "submit" since it hides the submit event. LASTLY, just hide the submit and show if valid

Comment: Also the test should be `if (Check && CheckAll()) {`

Comment: Also `var Check = document.getElementById("agree").checked;` is not a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues

1. you are missing a } - look at the code and the console. I marked it `// <------ missed a } here` in my code
2. NEVER call anything is a form "submit" since it hides the submit event
3. You expect to use a checkbox, so use a checkbox
4. Set the submit to disabled instead of changing style and type
5. You need to return false or true from checkAll

This code is not complete. Fix the above stuff first and then see why you alert the same thing twice

```js
function CheckAll() {
  var flag = true;
  var length = document.getElementById('user').value.length;
  var value = document.getElementById('user').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!(value.charAt(i) >= '0' && value.charAt(i) <= '9') || (value.charAt(i) >= 'a' && value.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (value.charAt(i) >= 'A' && value.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) {
      alert("username must be made of characters and numbers only");
      return false;
    }
  }
  var lengthPass = document.getElementById('password').value.length;
  var valuePass = document.getElementById('password').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < lengthPass; i++) {
    if (!(valuePass.charAt(i) >= '0' && valuePass.charAt(i) <= '9') || (valuePass.charAt(i) >= 'a' && valuePass.charAt(i) <= 'z') || (valuePass.charAt(i) >= 'A' && valuePass.charAt(i) <= 'Z')) {
      alert("Password must be made of characters and numbers only");
      return false;
    }

  }
  if (!(length >= 6 || length <= 20)) {
    alert("Username Must be 6-20 Characters long");
    return false;
  }
  if (!(lengthPass >= 6 || lengthPass <= 20)) {
    alert("Password must be 6-20 characters long")
    return false

  }
  var check = false;
  var valueMail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
  var shtrudel = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < valueMail.length; i++) {
    if (value.chatAt(i) == '@') {
      shtrudel++;
      for (var j = i; j < valueMail.length; j++) {
        if (valueMail.charAt(j) == '.') {
          check = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (shtrudel > 1) {
    alert("You're only allowed to have 1 '@' sign");
    return false
  }
  if (!check) {
    alert("Your email has to include a '@' sign and a '.' sign");
    return false;
  }
  var valuePhone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
  var lengthPgone = document.getElementById('phone').value.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!((valuePhone.charAt(i) >= '0' || valuePhone.charAt(i) <= '9') && (valuePhone.length != 7))) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
} // <------ missed a } here

function AgreeCheck() {
  document.getElementById("agree").checked = CheckAll();
  document.getElementById("sub").disabled = !CheckAll();
}
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url("Images/cup630.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150%;
}

form {
  color: red
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.cancelbtn,
.signupbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .cancelbtn,
  .signupbtn {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="HomePage.html" id="form">
  Name+Last Name: <input type="text" name="names" />
  <br />
  <br /> Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="user" />
  <br />
  <p style="font-size:70%">must contain 6-20 character</p>
  <br /> Password: <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
  <br />
  <p style="font-size:70%">must contain 6-20</p>
  <br /> E-mail: <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" />
  <br /> Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
  <br /> Enter Your Birth Date:
  <br />
  <br /> Day <input type="text" name="day" /> Month <input type="text" name="month" /> Year <input type="text" name="year" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Enter Your Favourite Esports Game:
  <select>
                <option>League Of Legends</option>
                <option>Dota</option>
                <option>StarCraft</option>
                <option>Street Fighter</option>
                <option>Smite</option>
                <option>Mortal Kombat</option>
                <option>Heroes Of The Storm</option>
                <option>Super Smash Bros</option>
                <option>Call of Duty</option>
                <option>Counter Strike: Global Offensive</option>
                <option>I Dont Watch Esports</option>
            </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree" value="check validity" onclick="AgreeCheck()" />
  <input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="submit" disabled/>
</form>
```

Comment: i did everything you said but know when i press the checkbox it shows "username must be made of characters and numbers only" a bunch of times until it dissapears and "password must be made of characters and numbers only"

Comment: As I said - more issues. I’m not going to spend more time fixing all your issues. Fix some more stuff and just return false when there is an error

Comment: See update - I return false where error and true at the end